# can I do this regex in just one step

Tags: regex

I have a following text

```
fd types:["a"] 
s types: 
  ["b","c"]
types: [
"one"
]
types: "two"
types: ["three", "four", "five","six"]
no: ["Don't","read","this"]
```

and I would like to extract just all types: **a** to **c**, **one** to **six**
I don't want to extract other properties like units
so far I can do this in two steps

```
(?:types:\s*\[\s*)(.+?)(?:\s*])|(?:types:\s*)(\".+?\")
```

this way I got the groups:

```
"a"
"b","c"
"one"
"two"  
"three", "four", "five","six"
```

then I apply

```
\s*"((?:[^",\s]*)*)"\s*
```

to any of the group and got

```
a
b
c
one
two  
three
four
five
six
```

I wonder if this can be done in just one step

Comment: What is the tool or language?

Comment: *"I wonder if this can be done in just one step"* - some regex engines - for example .NET - allow extracting all occurrences of a repeated group (i.e. the `"([^"]*)"` you would need to repeat inside the square brackets), but most engines only keep the last occurrence. You can theoretically do it with the right engine, but overall I would not recommend it. If you can run multiple steps, run multiple steps. It will be a lot more flexible and a lot easier to read.

Comment: I debug regex in this tool: https://regex101.com/r/igP3kX/1 , then I call it from python. When trying ``` (?:(?:\[|\"){1,2}|(?:\"\s*,\s*\"))(.+?)(?:(?:\]|\"){1,2}|(?:\"\s*,\s*\")) ``` it selects all words in doublequotes, but I want only members of types array not units array. I believe there is a way how to do all in one regex. Just for curiosity.

Comment: Try `(?:\G(?!^)\s*,\s*|types:(?:\s*\[)?\s*)"([^"]*)"`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/QvyYDu/1). In Python, you need to install `pip install regex` and then declare it as `import regex as re` and then use this pattern with `re.findall()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can `pip install` regex` and use

```
(?:\G(?!^)\s*,\s*|types:(?:\s*\[)?\s*)"([^"]*)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QvyYDu/1). *Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!^)\s*,\s*|types:(?:\s*\[)?\s*)` - either of the two patterns:

  - `\G(?!^)\s*,\s*` - end of the previous match and then a comma enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
  - `|` - or
  - `types:(?:\s*\[)?\s*` - `types:`, an optional sequence of zero or more whitespaces and a `[` char, and then zero or more whitespaces
- `"([^"]*)"` - `"`, then zero or more chars other than `"` captured into Group 1, and then a `"` char.

See the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##RY/NasMwEITvforNXCQFk0tugeJLoA8hOeDGci1IV0baJg7k3V05DeSwzM7HsD/TXcbI@2UJP1NMQsl/@7mqxM9CH6SGnuQ@@Xyw6NCS4/zypSWy@EKNM1rHL2odI7KH4zeD3CLeCciYvEdNGOJvemq4Fo8c5nUSxzV0jOyUFJp81xeRMWS0qqqmFFj088zdELjvLhedlG4O7lM3m5NxeVuXevyvW3neOmuaIgbantAWVTWtHxqzLH8):

```py
import regex

text = 'fd types:["a"] \ns types: \n  ["b","c"]\ntypes: [\n"one"\n]\ntypes: "two"\ntypes: ["three", "four", "five","six"]\nno: ["Don\'t","read","this"]'

print(regex.findall(r'(?:\G(?!^)\s*,\s*|types:(?:\s*\[)?\s*)"([^"]*)"', text))
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']
```